# How to test for verbal telicity

Tags: grammar, verbs

How would one test for verbal telicity in verbs, and why would it be usefull?

Comment: This question would be better asked at [linguistics.se], but you should explain more what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on linguistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A telic verb creates a referential bridge across a discontinuity.  After your house burns down, and consequently you have no house, you can rebuilt *it*, where "it" refers back to the old house which ceased to exist.  "Build" is telic.  But after your house burnt up, by way of comparison, you couldn't paint it mauve.  However, painting a portrait is telic, because the portrait is created by your painting of it.  So if an artist's portrait of his favorite wife was stolen, he could just paint *it* again.